# Accessing a variable inside a different class which requires a class argument in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Tkinter project, as it got bigger and bigger I started to use classes. After finally figuring out how to use multiple classes as frames, now I am stuck again with something new and couldn't find a solution.

I need to access a variable inside a class, which was defined inside another class. But at the original location where it was defined, the class takes an argument. So I am not able to call this variable unless I use an argument together with its class. But since my only purpose here is accessing this variable or even modify it, how can I do it without affecting the Tkinter widgets.

Also is this organization for a Tkinter program a good way to go? I've seen people doing it differently. Not sure if this organization is good or not.

```
import tkinter as tk

#Main Window
class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()   
        self.win.title("Class Tester")
        self.win.resizable("True", "True")     
        self.frame_1 = FirstFrame(self.win)        
        self.frame_2 = SecondFrame(self.win)       

 #First Frame       
class FirstFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent =parent
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Frame 1")
        self.frame1.pack()  
        self.show_widgets()      
    def show_widgets(self):
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Hi 1")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0)
    def a_fuction(self):
        self.var1 = 5 #Need to access this var from a different class
#Second Frame        
class SecondFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Frame 2")
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.show_widgets()
        self.b_fuction()
    def show_widgets(self):
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Hi 2")
        self.label2.grid(column=1, row=0)
    def b_fuction(self):
        self.var2 = FirstFrame().var1 
        #Tryig to access but requires class argument "parent".
        print(self.var2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainProgram().win
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Aren't you already passing the instance of the MainProgram?, i believe that's the way to go.

Comment: Just use `self.parent.frame1.var` inside any of the `xxxFrame` class' methods.

Answer (score 0):

To access an attribute in one instance from another instance, you just need a reference to that other instance.

Arguably the best solution is to let your `MainProgram` act as a controller. That is, `MainProgram` has knowledge of the other frames, and the other frames can ask it for a reference when they need it.

First, change `MainProgram` to pass itself to the other frames:

```
class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        ...     
        self.frame_1 = FirstFrame(self, self.win)        
        self.frame_2 = SecondFrame(self, self.win)
        ...

class FirstFrame():
    def __init__(self, main, parent):
        self.main = main
        ...

class SecondFrame():
    def __init__(self, main, parent):
        self.main = main
        ...
```

Next, you can use `self.main` to get the instance of the other frame:

```
class SecondFrame():
    ...  
    def b_fuction(self):
        first_frame = self.main.frame_1
        self.var2 = first_frame.var
```

Comment: I like this approach. This way if I try to call the variable using FirstFrame().var1, I won't get the error of not having to use a parent argument.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself asking "How do I get access to…", the answer is usually that you already had access to it, but threw it away, so the fix is to not do that.

In this case: the `SecondFrame` instance you want already exists, and the `MainProgram` instance knows about it, but the `FirstFrame` has no way to get back to its parent. It has a `parent` member, but that's just the `win` member of the `MainProgram`, not the `MainProgram` itself.

You're sort of mixing together two designs. Your organization is like the typical tkinter idiom of creating subclasses that inherit `Frame`, but you've adapted it to create independent classes that just *have* a `Frame` instead of *being* one.. Your design is fine—in fact, it's arguably better OO than the usual one (it's sort of halfway to a Model-View design)—but it means you need to keep track of the parent object, not just its window (that is, the model, not the view).

So, you could do something like this:

```
class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        # etc.
        self.frame_1 = FirstFrame(self)
        self.frame_2 = SecondFrame(self)

# ...

class SecondFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parentobj = parent
        self.parent = parent.win
        # etc.
    # and so on
    def b_fuction(self):
        self.var2 = self.parentobj.frame_1.var1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found before checking the replies here. While I am defining a variable inside a class, instead of using self.var, I used ClassXXX.var. This way I was able to access the variable inside other classes by calling it as ClassXXX.var.

```
import tkinter as tk

#Main Window
class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()   
        self.win.title("Class Tester")
        self.win.resizable("True", "True")     
        self.frame_1 = FirstFrame(self.win)        
        self.frame_2 = SecondFrame(self.win)       


#First Frame       
class FirstFrame():

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent =parent
        self.frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Frame 1")
        self.frame1.pack()  
        self.show_widgets()      
    def show_widgets(self):
        FirstFrame.var1 = 5 #Variable is declared in this style instead
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.frame1, text="Hi 1")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0)

#Second Frame        
class SecondFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Frame 2")
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.show_widgets()
        self.b_fuction()
    def show_widgets(self):
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.frame2, text="Hi 2")
        self.label2.grid(column=1, row=0)
    def b_fuction(self):
        self.var2 = FirstFrame.var1
        print(self.var2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainProgram().win
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you've already solve this problem in your code without noticing, since you already pass the instance of the parent class you can refer to variables between classes through that instance.

```
#Main Window
class MainProgram():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame_1 = FirstFrame(self)        
        self.frame_2 = SecondFrame(self)       

 #First Frame       
class FirstFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent =parent

    def a_fuction(self):
        self.parent.var1 = 5 

#Second Frame        
class SecondFrame():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent =parent
    def b_fuction(self):
        self.var2 = self.parent.var1
```

Here's a little example of what needs to be done.

Comment: No, this won't work, because `self.parent` is the `Frame` object that's owned by `MainProgram`, not the `MainProgram` itself.

Comment: `parent` isn't the instance of `MainProgram`, it's an instance of a frame inside the main program. Your code won't work because the frame doesn't have the `var1` attribute.